# Use Revtex 4.1 in Lyx or simply on linux

Tags: lyx, ubuntu, revtex, lyx-layouts

I am new to latex under Linux and I recently installed LyX on an Ubuntu derivative and as we all know a lot of the provided templates don't work, one particular one that I am really interested in getting to work is the Revtex one, the error message I get is as follows:

```
Using revtex.lyx template:

LaTeX Error: File 'revtex.sty' not found. 

Description: 

 \renewcommand
                  {\usepackage}{\RequirePackage}^^M
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)

Using revtex4.lyx template: 

The layout file requested by this document,
revtex4.layout,
is not usable. This is probably because a LaTeX
class or style file required by it is not
available. See the Customization documentation
for more information.
LyX will not be able to produce output.
```

Now I do realize that the style and the layout files are missing, can anyone please guide me so I can install it it properly, I think I need to put the files somewhere LyX can see them, how do I do that?. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 8):

I think you need to install the `texlive-publishers` Ubuntu package.

```
apt-get install texlive-publishers
```